# SKPhysicsBody moving even when velocity is 0

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have constructed a maze out of 32x32 square png's, and an SKPhysicsBody has been applied to them for the purpose of blocking the player from traveling through them (the player is not shown here)

For some strange reason, some squares within the maze are moving at a very tiny speed (coordinates are changing, and they are slowly moving on the screen), but their SKPhysicsBody.velocity is 0 on both axes

In an attempt to figure this out, I setup some minimal code that reproduces the environment, and this code highlights the squares that are moving in blue. Code is at the bottom of this post

**Features of the code**

- allows you to use the arrow keys on your keyboard to move the entire maze on the screen ... this causes the squares highlighted to change, and there are some curious patterns when you do this
- allows you to click any square so that it's position and velocity is inputted in the console ... the blue squares have a constantly changing position, but a 0 velocity

**Facts**

- Commenting out the SKPhysicsBody declaration in BrokenTile causes the problem to go away, but since I wish to have collision detection, this is not an appropriate solution for me
- When moving the maze around using arrow keys, it changes which groups of squares are blue, but there appear to be patterns. It is always an entire row or column that is blue, and sometimes both.
- Even the white squares, when the maze is initially spawned, are not at their perfect coordinates, and are shifted slightly before settling down (which would be in multiples of 34 due to the size setting in BrokenWorld.load)

Anybody have any ideas what is causing the blue squares to be moving at tiny amounts even though velocity is 0?

*edit*: I attempted to add an extension to SKSpriteNode that alerts me whenever the spritenode changes. I have confirmed that changing x inside of position causes willSet to fire, but it only seems to fire when my code changes the value directly. Is there some reason it is not firing when position is being changed by whatever unknown process is causing it to move around? I was hoping to put a breakpoint here to get a stack that tells me exactly where the change is coming from

```
extension SKSpriteNode {
    open override var position: CGPoint {
        willSet {
            print("Position of \(self) will change to: \(newValue)")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Squares in blue are moving]

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import Carbon.HIToolbox.Events  // kVK

class IssuePhysics: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    
    static var instance: IssuePhysics?
    
    var world = BrokenWorld()
    var keys = [Int: Bool]()
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        IssuePhysics.instance = self
        
        let O = "e"
        let X = "b"
        
        // Load Map
        let map = [
            [O, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X],
            [X, O, X, O, O, O, O, X, O, O, O, O, X, X],
            [X, O, X, O, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, O, X, X],
            [X, O, X, O, O, O, O, X, O, O, O, O, X, X],
            [X, O, X, X, X, X, O, X, O, X, X, O, X, X],
            [X, O, O, O, O, O, O, X, O, O, X, O, X, X],
            [X, X, X, X, X, O, X, X, X, O, X, O, X, X],
            [X, O, O, O, X, O, X, O, X, O, X, O, X, X],
            [X, O, X, O, X, O, X, O, X, O, X, O, X, X],
            [X, O, X, O, X, O, X, O, X, O, X, O, X, X],
            [X, O, X, O, O, O, O, O, O, O, X, O, X, X],
            [X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X]
        ]
        
        world.load(map: map)
        
        
        addChild(world)
        world.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
        
    }
    
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        // Get mouse position in scene coordinates
        let location = event.location(in: self)
        // Get node at mouse position
        let node = self.atPoint(location)
        print((node.name ?? "empty") + ": " + node.position.debugDescription)
        print((node.physicsBody?.velocity.debugDescription) as Any)
        
    }
    
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        keys[Int(event.keyCode)] = true
    }
    
    override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        keys[Int(event.keyCode)] = false
    }
    
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        world.update(keys: keys)
    }
    
}

class BrokenWorld : SKNode {
    
    static var instance: BrokenWorld?
    
    var coords = [[BrokenTile]]()
    static let squareSize = 32
    var tile_templates = [String: BrokenTile]()
    
    override init(){
        super.init()
        BrokenWorld.instance = self
        self.name = "world"
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func load(map: [[String]]){
        
        
        var tile = BrokenTile()
        tile_templates["e"] = tile   // register empty tile
        tile = BrokenTile(imageNamed: "Blocker")
        tile.initPhysics()
        tile_templates["b"] = tile   // register standard white tile
        
        let size = 34  // deliberately higher than 32 so that each square in the maze is clearly visible
        
        self.coords = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: BrokenTile(), count: map.count), count: map[0].count)
        for y in 0...map.count-1 {
            for x in 0...map[y].count-1 {
                let tile_tmp = tile_templates[map[y][x]]!.clone()
                tile_tmp.position = CGPoint(x: x*size, y: y*size)
                self.coords[x][y] = tile_tmp
                self.addChild(self.coords[x][y])
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func update(keys: [Int: Bool]){
        for row in self.coords {
            for tile in row {
                tile.update(keys: keys)
            }
        }
        if keys[kVK_LeftArrow] ?? false {
            self.position.x -= 10
        } else if keys[kVK_RightArrow] ?? false {
            self.position.x += 10
        } else if keys[kVK_UpArrow] ?? false {
            self.position.y += 10
        } else if keys[kVK_DownArrow] ?? false {
            self.position.y -= 10
        }
    }
    
}

class BrokenTile : SKSpriteNode {
    
    var imageName: String = "empty"
    var lastPosition: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    var changeTimer = 0
    
    init(imageNamed: String){
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNamed)
        self.imageName = imageNamed
        super.init(texture: texture, color: SKColor.clear, size: texture.size())
        self.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        self.name = "tile"
    }
    
    init(){
        super.init(texture: nil, color: SKColor.clear, size: CGSize(width: 32, height: 32))
        self.name = "tile"
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func initPhysics(){
        // commenting out next two lines resolves the problem, but then collission cannot be enabled, so that is not a satisfactory solution
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: self.size)
        self.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
    }
    
    func update(keys: [Int: Bool]){
        if self.lastPosition.x != self.position.x || self.lastPosition.y != self.position.y {
            self.lastPosition.x = self.position.x
            self.lastPosition.y = self.position.y
            changeTimer = 1
        }
        
        if self.imageName == "Blocker" {
            if changeTimer > 0 {
                self.color = SKColor.blue
                changeTimer -= 1
            } else {
                self.color = SKColor.white
            }
        }
    }
    
    func clone() -> BrokenTile {
        let clone = self.copy() as! BrokenTile
        clone.imageName = self.imageName
        return clone
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a minimally reproducible example. otherwise, you're asking to help you debug, and you all you showed was 3 lines of code.

Comment: Can you strip your code down t just placing the node on-scren and then doing nothing, other than print their co-ordinates (once a second perhaps) in update()? Do they still move?

Comment: I commented out the update(...) and didBegin(...) methods in GameScene.swift (nothing else executes those methods in other classes). As expected, I lost all ability to move the player or camera, but moving squares are still moving