# Is there a way to add willSet parameter to a struct's instance variable?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to do something along these lines:

```
class MyCGPoint: CGPoint {
    override public x: CGFloat {
        willSet {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Naturally, I find out that classes cannot extend Structs, so I am unsure how to attach a willSet method to the x variable that is already present in CGPoint

I am open to alternatives to this approach. The reason I am trying to do this is so that I can add a breakpoint into that willSet method, and determine what is causing the position of my SKSpriteNode to change (even though physics body velocity is 0)

See [SKPhysicsBody moving even when velocity is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63429923/1127161) for the problem I am trying to diagnose with this technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need this for debugging you could [use a watchpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH8-SW9), a symbolic breakpoint on `-[SKSpriteNode setPosition:]` (I didn't test this out though) or even an extension on `SKSpriteNode` with something like this:

```
extension SKSpriteNode {
    open override var position: CGPoint {
        willSet {
            print("Position of \(self) will change to: \(newValue)")
            // Breakpoint here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I was considering trying this next, but the potential downside to this is that the willSet method will not execute if the offending code is modifying x or y directly. Unless CGPoint is immutable?

Comment: I tried that extension, and it at least confirms that whatever is changing the x/y values, it is changing them directly (because this willSet does not execute during the problem, but does execute other times when I know I changed the position variable). Is there a way to do this directly to the x or y variable within the CGPoint struct? I am unsure how I could use a watchpoint here, since that requires me to place a breakpoint from the start, and my problem is that I don't have a place to put the breakpoint

Comment: @Furyvore It wouldn't matter. Setting `node.position.x = <some_value>` would trigger `wiiSet` observer. You can try it in a playground.

Comment: Interesting, you're right, the willSet fires anyway. So we have a position value that changes without changing the position reference, nor the x/y values inside .. how is that possible?

Comment: If you could provide a _minimal_ reproducible example I would be happy to have a look at it.

Comment: I have a separate stack overflow question with those details (see the link in my question here)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to subclass struct (Swift doesn't allow you to do this). Just create your own Point with the same signatures, and a method to convert to `CGPoint` from your Point. Then replace `CGPoint` in your implementation with the new Point

```
struct MyPoint {
  var x: CGFloat {
    willSet {
    
    }
  }
  var y: CGFloat

  var cgPoint: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: x, y: y) }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, when you say "replace CGPoint in your implementation", the implementation in question is SKSpriteNode.position, which is not "mine", nor am I free to modify it. Though, would this work in conjuction with Alladinian's answer without causing other things to break?